# Protecting ICR batteries

Tags: batteries

Is there a way that I can add protection circuitry to a non-protected ICR cell?  I purchased an order of Panasonic cells at a discount, and I would like to keep them safe.

Would buying cheep cells, such as "UltraFire" 18350 cells, taking the circuit and putting it on my nice cells be a legit solution?

Comment: You could buy cheap protection PCBs.

Comment: Did I answer your question or would you like some additional info?

Answer (score 1):

I would buy just the PCB. You can get a new and good quality Protective PCB cheaper that you can get a very low end, such as UltraFire, batter with a PCB and you will know it is new. UltraFire is known for reusing old cells so I could see them using old PCBs too.

Be sure to check the requirements of the cell and match them with the values of the PCB. Over discharge can shorten the battery life but short circuiting can have a spectacular outcome. You definitely need a PCB to prevent accidental battery explosion due to their extra high energy density.

As you can see [here](http://www.batteryjunction.com/pcb.html) and [here](http://www.batteryspace.com/protectioncircuitmodulepcbfor36vli-ionbattery875malimit.aspx) the PCBs can be pretty cheap.

Be cautious when attaching the PCB to the battery. It isn't a good idea to solder directly on the cell. I have seen a lot of batteries that use a plastic wrapper to hold the PCB to the cell to make it's contact. The supplier of your PCB will have a info on how to best connect the PCB to the cell.